# Where can I buy fenders that enclose the wheel partially, like rental bikes usually have?

Tags: fenders, city

How can I find those true mudguards that rental bikes usually have? I don't know what terms to search for or which shops to look in.

These images show the fenders I am looking for:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: Search for "skirt/dress guard".

Comment: Also, the fenders you've pictured really aren't all that effective in keeping mud off you.  The front wheel will still spray mud, water, and road debris onto you.  To stop the spray, the front fender needs to extend a lot lower, and needs to be wider, too.  Good fenders will have a flap that extends down towards the ground to stop the spray.

Comment: The mudguards in those pictures are quite different. The front wheel fenders in 3, for example, are completely ordinary. Is the main thing you require the side plate? Also, asking which online store sells them is off-topic.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Depending on the speed and tyres, the front fenders also have to extend quite a ways forward and to the sides in front of the fork to catch all the water being thrown to the front and subsequently into one's face.

Comment: @Erlkoenig Consider writing that as an answer? Alex, do note that per our FAQ, we don't typically act as a shopping guide (e.g. give info which stores to look for products in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The side guards on the rear wheel are called "skirt guard" or "dress guard". They are commonly found on Dutch bikes. Apparently searching for the Dutch term "Jasbeschermer" is also helpful and gives you products like this:

[image]

They are mostly intended to stop loose clothing from getting tangled in the wheel. This only makes sense if you also use a chain guard.

If you only want to stop the spray by dirt/water, but don't need the tangling protection, use regular full-length fenders:

[image]